# D3 Graphs in Rails: multiple Js files overlapping

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, d3.js, svg

I have three .js files that should be rendering d3 line charts on a view in a certain order.

The question: how do I get a .js file to not overwrite another when both need to display graphs on the same view?

They are separate because they pull in different data.

*Files 'a' and 'b', should render graphs if 'a' finds data via ajax call. If not, file 'c' should render.*

They will work independently! But when all files are present, they either wont load or one will load three times :/

The main view:

```
  <% elsif !@a.empty? %>
    <%= render 'a/graphs' %>
    <%= render 'b/graphs' unless b.empty? %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'c/graphs' %>
  <% end %>
```

The form helpers:

'a/graphs'

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">


<div class="table-responsive">
<div id="flow_plot" class="plot">       </div>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive">
<div id="ph_plot" class="plot">       </div>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive">
<div id="turbidity_plot" class="plot">     </div>
</div>

</div>
```

'b/graphs'

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">


<div class="table-responsive">
<div id="zinc_plot" class="plot">       </div>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive">
<div id="copper_plot" class="plot">     </div>
</div>

</div>
```

'c/graphs'

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">


<div class="table-responsive">
<div id="temperature_plot" class="plot">       </div>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive">
<div id="velocity_plot" class="plot">       </div>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive">
<div id="depth_plot" class="plot">     </div>
</div>

</div>
```

When this works gets the right form helper, it does not get the right .js file. It will get all of them, causing all sorts of problems including Parse issues.

I have these in each of my Js files (the plot id is the first 'svg' on each page, where 'loadData' is where the ajax and d3 is):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if($("#" + "zinc_plot").length == 1) {
        loadData();
    }
```

});

It doesn't quite work. What will happen is, file 'a' will correctly display all of it's charts, but will then display them 2 more times(1 time for each additional js file) but without correct time formatting and lines.

So, in my .js file I want to tell it to only load the data if it needs to. Would changing the above conditional be my best bet? Let me know if I can provide more info, thanks so much!

Extra info:

This is file 'a.js'

```
// ajax call to fetch json
var loadData = function() {
  var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
  var site_id = path[path.length - 1];
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: '/a.json?site_id=' + site_id + '&graphable=true',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      var alldata = [];
      var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");
      data.forEach(function(data) {
        //this algorithm just sorts it into a nested array for graphing purposes
        var eachmp = []
        for (var idx = 0; idx < data.scute_reports.length; idx++) {
          var thisobject = {}
          thisobject.name = data.name
          thisobject.inspected_at = parseTime(data.scute_reports[idx].inspected_at)
          thisobject.zinc_data = data.scute_reports[idx].zinc
          thisobject.copper_data = data.scute_reports[idx].copper
          eachmp.push(thisobject)
        }
        alldata.push(eachmp)
      });

      console.log(alldata)
      formatAllThree(alldata)
    },

    failure: function(result) {
      error();
      console.log("fail")
    }
  });
};

function error() {
  console.log("Something went wrong!");
}

function formatAllThree(data) {
  drawLinePlot_flow(data);
  drawLinePlot_ph(data);
  drawLinePlot_turbidity(data);

  function drawLinePlot_flow(data) {
    var svg = d3.select("#flow_plot").append("svg")
    //d3 code
  }

  function drawLinePlot_ph(data) {
    var svg = d3.select("#ph_plot").append("svg")
    //d3 code
  }

  function drawLinePlot_turbidity(data) {
    var svg = d3.select("#turbidity_plot").append("svg")
    //d3 code
  }

}

// fetch data on page load
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#" + "flow_plot").length == 1) {
    loadData();
  }
});
```

This is file 'b'

```
// ajax call to fetch json
var loadData = function() {
  var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
  var site_id = path[path.length - 1];
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: '/lab_forms.json?site_id=' + site_id + '&graphable=true',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      var alldata = [];
      var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");
      data.forEach(function(data) {
        //this algorithm just sorts it into a nested array for graphing purposes
        var eachmp = []
        for (var idx = 0; idx < data.scute_reports.length; idx++) {
          var thisobject = {}
          thisobject.name = data.name
          thisobject.inspected_at = parseTime(data.scute_reports[idx].inspected_at)
          thisobject.zinc_data = data.scute_reports[idx].zinc
          thisobject.copper_data = data.scute_reports[idx].copper
          eachmp.push(thisobject)
        }
        alldata.push(eachmp)
      });

      console.log(alldata)
      formatAllThree(alldata)
    },

    failure: function(result) {
      error();
      console.log("fail")
    }
  });
};

function error() {
  console.log("Something went wrong!");
}

function formatAllThree(data) {
  drawLinePlot_zinc(data);
  drawLinePlot_copper(data);

  function drawLinePlot_Zinc(data) {
    var svg = d3.select("#zinc_plot").append("svg")
    //d3 code
  }

  function drawLinePlot_Copper(data) {
    var svg = d3.select("#copper_plot").append("svg")
    //each js file calls different id's
    //d3 code
  }
}

// fetch data on page load
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#" + "zinc_plot").length == 1) {
    loadData();
  }
});
```

This is file 'c'

```
// ajax call to fetch json
var loadData = function() {
  var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
  var site_id = path[path.length - 1];
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: '/lab_forms.json?site_id=' + site_id + '&graphable=true',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      var alldata = [];
      var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");
      data.forEach(function(data) {
        //this algorithm just sorts it into a nested array for graphing purposes
        var eachmp = []
        for (var idx = 0; idx < data.scute_reports.length; idx++) {
          var thisobject = {}
          thisobject.name = data.name
          thisobject.inspected_at = parseTime(data.scute_reports[idx].inspected_at)
          thisobject.zinc_data = data.scute_reports[idx].zinc
          thisobject.copper_data = data.scute_reports[idx].copper
          eachmp.push(thisobject)
        }
        alldata.push(eachmp)
      });

      console.log(alldata)
      formatAllThree(alldata)
    },

    failure: function(result) {
      error();
      console.log("fail")
    }
  });
};

function error() {
  console.log("Something went wrong!");
}

function formatAllThree(data) {
  drawLinePlot_temp(data);
  drawLinePlot_velocity(data);
  drawLinePlot_depth(data);

  function drawLinePlot_temp(data) {
    var svg = d3.select("#temperature_plot").append("svg")
    //d3 code
  }

  function drawLinePlot_velocity(data) {
    var svg = d3.select("#velocity_plot").append("svg")
    //each js file calls different id's
    //d3 code
  }

  function drawLinePlot_depth(data) {
    var svg = d3.select("#depth_plot").append("svg")
    //each js file calls different id's
    //d3 code
  }
}

// fetch data on page load
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#" + "temperature_plot").length == 1) {
    loadData();
  }
});
```

Comment: how do you load your js files, I'm pretty sure all of them get loaded into the DOM and thats why you have graphs overlapping each other, can you show your js files and how you load them

Comment: Sure! So here's some Js code and html. I omitted the actual d3 code for brevity. All three files are essentially like this, just with different names and such.
https://codepen.io/lahesty/pen/QxXKyP

Comment: are those 3 graphs in the same view or different view ?

Comment: One view will render either: 2 graphs from one form helper and 3 from another, or, 3 graphs from a third form helper. So if the first file doesn't pull up data, neither of those will display and the last three will. i.e. the first code sample

Comment: unless you edit the question to make it more clear I really can't help you

Comment: Alright I added the code for the three files. How it should be: File 'a.js' will d3.select a div from form-helper 'a' for example. If 'a.js' returns data,  a & b will render in the view. If not, 'c' will. Thanks

Comment: what is your `@a` in main view ?

Comment: That is the instance variable to which the data called in file a.js belongs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174465/discussion-between-subash-and-laurenah).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what was going on, and why the files were interacting strangely.

What was going on was in each loadData function in each of the javaScript files, I would call a function that contained all of my d3 code.

```
formatAllThree(alldata)
```

then...

```
function formatAllThree(data) {
 //all of my d3 code
}
```

Problem is: *That function had the same name in each file.* The first one would load and display accordingly, but as soon as *formatAllThree(alldata)* was called in the second file, it would jump back to the first time the function was written out, in the first file. It would never run my d3 code in the other files.

To fix this, I gave that function a different name in each JavaScript file, i.e.

```
formatAllThree_A(alldata)
```

I do not need to put in a conditional at the bottom of each JavaScript file that looks to see if a certain id exists on the view, such as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#" + "zinc_plot").length == 1) {
    loadData();
  }
});
```